# option + enter for quick fix is not working in latest android studio

Tags: android-studio

Option+Enter for quick fix seems to work just fine from within Kotlin files. I can use it to generate methods on the fly, but the keystroke is completely ignored in java files. I reset the keymaps to default, restored defaults for the inspections, and invalidated the AndroidStudio caches and restarted.

I'm not sure how to re-enable this setting on 3.0.1, build number 171.4443003. Does anyone know why this might have stopped working or what I can do to re-enable it?

Comment: Really? With the same build as you, I'm seeing the exact opposite: the keystrokes are still fine and dandy on java, but no sign of working on kotlin files.  I assumed it has something to do with kotlin (just learning it now).  Sigh.

Comment: Ok, new project, and the option-enter quick fix is working on kotlin files.  Still not working on the first project.  Hmmm